# How to save many-to-many relationship without using nested form in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm super new to RoR. I'm building a video uploader which is many-to-many relationship with tags. So one video can have many tags and one tag can belong to many videos. As far as I know nested form can do this but I don't want to have multiple text fields. I just want one text field and separated by space.

Here's my model.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :video_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :video_tags

end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :video_tags
    has_many :videos, through: :video_tags
end

class VideoTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

And this is my form

```
<%= form_for(@video, html: { class: "directUpload" }, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @video.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :path %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :path%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my `Controller`

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @videos = Video.where(user_id: params[:user_id])

  end

  def new
        @video = Video.new
    @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public_read)
  end


  def create
    tags = params[:tags].split(' ').map { |tag|
        Tag.new(title: tag) 
    }

    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    @video.user_id = 1
    @video.tags = tags

    if @video.save
        redirect_to @video
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def video_params
        params.require(:video).permit(:title, :path, :tags)
  end

end


class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :videos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :path
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :videos, :users
  end
end

class CreateTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateVideoTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags_videos do |t|
      t.references :video, index: true
      t.references :tag, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :tags_videos, :videos
    add_foreign_key :tags_videos, :tags
  end
end
```

Of course that this doesn't work undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

> undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your `create` controller function might not be working is because you're not using `video_params`. It's possible that `params[:video][:tags]` is what you mean instead of `params[:tags]`. I would also suggest adding tags after the video saves.

```
def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    @video.user_id = 1 # add a current_user function in your application controller, and then use current_user.id

    if @video.save
        tags.each { |tag| Tag.create(title: tag, video_id: @video.id) }
        redirect_to @video
    end
  end

private

def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(:title, :path)
end

def tags
    params[:video][:tags].split(" ")
end
```

You may also want to use the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association for a many to many relationship.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
end
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error `undefined method `each' for "test test1":String`

Comment: I forgot to `.split`. I updated the code a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like you added `video_id` field to `Tag` table which I don't have it. I will post my migration script to see if something is wrong.

Comment: After I deleted `video_id` it's working fine but table `tags_videos` doesn't have any data.

Comment: You can add an `attr_accessor` for the video_id, and create the `tag_video` model in an `after_create` callback in the `tag` model